# Multiply a 5D matrix with a 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, dot-product

I have a 5D matrix Cij(3,3,Nx,Ny,Nz) where Nx,Ny and Nz are given as input.

I need to perform something like this:

```
for ikx=1:Nx,
    for iky=1:Ny,
        for ikz=1:Nz,

            %Random simulation of fourier components
            n=zeros((3),'double');
            for j=1:9,
                ncomponent=randn(2);
                n(j)=complex(ncomponent(1),ncomponent(2));
                %Calculation of H
                H(:,ikx,iky,ikz)=dot(Cij(:,:,ikx,iky,ikz),n);
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

The problem is that increasing Nx,Ny,Nz the loop requires a real huge time to get the H matrix calculated.

Does anybody know any faster way to get H matrix?

Answer (score 3):

It should first be noted that within your inner-most loop you perform the dot product 9 times, overwriting `H(:,ikx,iky,ikz)` each time. There's no point to that. You should just fill in the random values for `n` *within* the loop, and compute `H(:,ikx,iky,ikz)` once *after* that loop.

However, all the loops are unnecessary since you can take advantage of the fact that the function [DOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dot.html) is vectorized and can handle 5-D arrays (i.e. it will automatically perform the dot operation across the first non-singleton dimension). All you have to do is make `n` a 3-by-3-by-Nx-by-Ny-by-Nz matrix of complex values. These two lines should give you the same result as your code above:

```
n = complex(rand([3 3 Nx Ny Nz]), rand([3 3 Nx Ny Nz]));
H = squeeze(dot(Cij, n));
```

The function [SQUEEZE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/squeeze.html) is used to remove singleton dimensions from `H`, which will make it a 3-by-Nx-by-Ny-by-Nz matrix.

Comment: The final H matrix has to be 4D ,neither 5D nor 3D.

H represent a 3D turbulent field over a spatial grid made up of (Nx,Ny,Nz) elements.

So that from Cij(3,3,Nx,Ny,Nz), I want to get a final H(3,Nx,Ny,Nz) matrix which stores the turbulent field.

I thank you in advance and I'm sorry to bother you with trivial queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using some `reshape` (and `permute`)

```
C=rand(3,3,Nx,Ny,Nz);
n=rand(3,3);
```

If you want a mtrix multiplication between n and each element of C:

```
H=reshape(n*reshape(C,3,3*Nx*Ny*Nz),[3,3,Nx,Ny,Nz])
```

If you want a dot product between n and each element of C:

```
H=reshape(reshape(n,1,[])*reshape(C,3*3,Nx*Ny*Nz),[Nx,Ny,Nz])
```

Comment: This does not appear to reproduce what is being done in the nested loops.

Comment: Yes, but the code does not appear to be really what he wants to do... He said "something like that". His code does not multiply a 5D matrix with a 2D matrix, as said in the title... I think he misplaced several parts of the code, the loop on j should be at the beginning and not nested with the others. That's my guess about what he wants to do. Maybe I am wrong...

Comment: Hmmm, I had interpreted his title as being a little off, and that the code he wrote was giving him the right answer, but just not as quickly as he wanted it to. I guess we'll have to wait and see how he comments on our answers.

Comment: Hallo guys,I thank you for the real early reply.Probably I failed to explain what I need to perform: My starting matrix is 5D Cij(3,3,Nx,Ny,Nz) and I wanna get the final 4D matrix H(3,Nx,Ny,Nz) by multiplying each sub-matrix Cij(3,3) with another 2D matrix n(3,3),where n is made up of complex number with mu=0.0; and sigma=1.0; I hope of having explained in a better way my issue this time. Please be patient with me,I am still a newbee with matlab.

Comment: 1) If you do the dot product between Cij(3,3) and n(3,3) then the result is a scalar and your final output is of size H(Nx,Ny,Nz)      2) If you do the matrix multiplcation the result is a 3x3 matrix so the final output is of size H(3,3,Nx,Ny,Nz)

Comment: @FrancescoPerrone: Multiplying two 3-by-3 matrices will give you another 3-by-3 matrix, which means `H` will have to be the same size as `Cij` (i.e. 5-D).

Comment: I am a dumbass :(...the first answer making use of the squeeze function is the closest to the results I want to get. I don't know how to explain everything in a better way. From Cij, I need to get the final H(3,Nx,Ny,Nz):its elements are all complex numbers with gaussian distribution (mu=0,sigma=1.0). Hopefully this will help you to figure what I mean.. I feel really stupid!!!